# Force rotating screen stuck up with only landscape mode

Tags: java, android

In my `Activity` I have button if I click on the button am rotating the screen to landscape mode, But it stuck up with only landscape mode. How to enable the portrait mode? I am using the below code for force rotation.

```
   rotate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
   }

});
```

the above code override the native rotation functionality, Could any one please suggest me how to enable the native rotation function?

Comment: I am sorry Here after I wont tag like that

Comment: If you set that flag, you are forcing it to be landscape and therefore won't switch back to portrait if the phone is rotated.

Comment: oh okay, How can I achieve both functionality?

Comment: If you change the orientation manually you have to undo it manually too. Take a look at the doc (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)

Answer (score 1):

Programatically You can do it with this code

```
potraitButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
   }

});

buttonLandscape.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
   }

});
```

if you want to rotate screen automatic:

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {
            int orientation=-1;;

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                if (event.values[1]<6.5 && event.values[1]>-6.5) {
                    if (orientation!=1) {
                        Log.d("Sensor", "Landscape");
                    }
                    orientation=1;
                } else {
                    if (orientation!=0) {
                        Log.d("Sensor", "Portrait");
                    }
                    orientation=0;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {


            }
        }, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

Comment: That is not the right way to handle screen rotation. Please take a look at android doc (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)

Comment: In my case I have button click for landscape rotation, and then if the user rotate the device to portrait or landscape then it should work both orientation

Comment: so you have to make an static varible or any count and change value of that when user change rotation and update value of count.

Comment: after the force rotation no orientation methods are calling in this case how can I get the counts?

Comment: when user press the button , you have to change value of count and then user again press button , you have to check value of count and on each click you have to check value of count , according to value of count , change the the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two option.

First you can switch back to portrait manually **whenever** you want using: `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Another way is to override the `onConfigurationChanged()` (take a look at the doc [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)).
Example:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(changedOrientationManually && 
         newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        //Logic (maybe setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);)
    }
}
```

You can achieve your goal both ways, it depends on **when** you want to go back to portrait.

Comment: after calling this setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); the onConfigurationChanged is not working

Comment: even I rotating the device

Comment: Please update your question with the new code and specify **where** you are (activity, fragment, whatever). The onConfigurationChanged()  is called after you rotate the smartphone.

Comment: I don't have any button clicks for portrait it should happen when the user rotate the device to portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Create one global variable as

```
boolean landscape = false;
```

then while clicking button;

```
rotate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 if(!landscape){
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
 landscape = true;
 }else{
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
 landscape = false;
 }
}});
```

So if you click the button again it'll switch to portrait mode again.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my scenario, I have the button click only for force landscape mode not for the portrait

Comment: I am using the same button for both the purpose. If you click again it'll go back to portrait

Comment: But the goal is not to go back to portrait mode? It's to reactivate the automatic screen orientation that setRequestedOrientation ruined.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding

```
   this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

overrides the orientation you defined for that activity in AndroidManifest, e.g.:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```

To get the automatic orientation changes back you need to reset the orientation:

```
 this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

See my own question: [Switch activiy on orientation changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58554769/switch-activiy-on-orientation-changed/58589258#58589258)